# Mean well power supply for rpi through GPIO

Tags: power-supply

I have a [Mean Well](https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-dual-output-enclosed-power-supply-output-rd--125a) Switching power supply 5V. I have connected 5V output to rpi's 3b+ gpio pins to power it up, but the supply is just going up/down like it has no power drain.
can you recommend how to make it hold the voltage?

EDIT: photo, as requested:
[image]
[image]

thanks

Comment: How much power (Amps) does the power supply deliver? Make sure the current limit is set to at least 3Amps.

Comment: What is the specification of the power supply? What cables are you using to connect to the Pi?

Comment: it's 7A i believe. a lot.. just a reular thin cables :D

Comment: Have you got a link to the PSU? Don't use thin cables for power.

Comment: this one: https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-dual-output-enclosed-power-supply-output-rd--125a
well how thick cable do you recommend to connect to gpio to power rpi?!

Comment: Why such a big psu? Cable should be min 18AWG or 1.0237mm diameter as per the official power supply. You could double up 5V and Gnd feeds? Hopefully no other junctions between psu and pi.

Comment: well, I'm powering a peltier module alongside with it. it needs a strong psu. and I cannot use much thicker cables it just won't fit into gpio's removable connection (I don't know how to say it)

Comment: what I really need is something that's gonna dry more power from the psu before the rpi for psu to say switched on

Comment: How exactly did you connect the PSU?

Comment: Post a photo of your psu to Pi wiring.

Comment: @greengold All the information you have added in comments should have been edited into your question.

Comment: photo added; @joan, i don't consider information given in this discussion to be that much of a breaking news

Comment: It looks like you just wired it backwards from your photo. Check the pinout of the Pi https://pinout.xyz/#

Comment: @RobBricheno, it just looks like that. a cable is twisted, if it would be upsidedown rpi wouldnt even light up, but if you are reading carefully enough i say it goes up and down so I need a way to increase power drain.

Comment: I also use MeanWell PSUs and never cam across a PSU that powers off... they have a steady voltage even without any load. You should check your wiring for shorts.

Comment: @kwasmich no shorts :) checked. thanks

Comment: @kwasmich i had a short before. that 7A started to melt cables in 3seconds. no shorts now. i would know that ;)

Comment: Thanks for the second photo, that makes it clearer. It's useful to know that the Pi lights up. I would unplug everything except the power lines to the Pi. Does it power up and stay on? If no, then try another power supply (or another Pi). If yes, then start plugging things in until it stops working. That's the thing that's broken.

Comment: no, it's not any helpful, your distracted from the problem I'm tryin to solve here (to increase pi's power drain for this psu) by the wiring that is alright.

Answer (score 2):

The [Meanwell RD-125A power supply](https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-dual-output-enclosed-power-supply-output-rd--125a) that you are using implements a feature called ["Hiccup Mode"](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/TechTip/power-supply-hiccup-mode.html) which is triggered when the load on the primary channel is too low. So this is expected behaviour.

[Somebody on Amazon worked around this by adding a resistor as a dummy load, and wrote it up in their review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1SSVNNR835U6D/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B005T7GGPC), but this doesn't seem like a great idea to me.

I'd use a different power supply, or use a buck converter from the stable 12V supply (if it *is* stable, and not also resetting when hiccup mode kicks in) to get 5V for the Pi.

Comment: Upon close inspection the datasheet says "it is recommended that CH1 load > 15% rated current". There's a big mental leap between that statement and the observed behavior. If the issue is confirmed, I'd try to return this supply back as defective and use a different one, like you said. I have a similar no-name supply which works perfectly at any current / voltage combination within the range.

Comment: yeah that's basically right but I doesn't like the resistor idea much too. can't even buy 50W resistor here...
@DmitryGrigoryev observed behaviour matches the described one: it really doesnt hold up wirh load like rpi is. >15% is way too high. what psu do you use?

Comment: @greengold 15% of the rated current (7.7A) is 1.15A. You don't need a 50W resistor to dissipate 5V*1.15A=5.7W, 5-10W will do. My PSU is hjs-480-0-48: it's adjustable in the range of 0-48V and 0-10A. They have 5V and 12V variants as well.